# Any possibility that Ola Hallengren could add a job name prefix option to the script that creates all the maintenance jobs?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, maintenance, ola-hallengren

When creating the jobs, they sort together for most of them, but some of the jobs are alphabetically far away from the other Ola jobs on servers with hundreds of jobs.

I would find it easier to see all the jobs within SQL Server Agent if all the jobs sorted together alphabetically.

If they had the same prefix in the job name, that could happen.  But many people have these jobs installed with the traditional names so adding a prefix would be an excellent option that wouldn't mess up old installations that are being replaced.

The length of the prefix would need to be limited so the job names were less than 256 characters, but other than that it would be cool if we could optionally add "OLA - " or "OH - " or something of the sort to the beginning of the job names so all the jobs sorted together.

Is that a reasonable request?  Is there a better place to request features like this than here in StackExchange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be included as part of the solution, maybe add a request to the [GitHub repo for the Maintenance Solution](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues).

Alternatively, you can alter the deployment script for your particular environment to handle this. In the **MaintenanceSolution.sql** deployment script, there is a table variable called **@Jobs** that holds each of the jobs to be created.

You could add a line after line 9014 to update the **Name** column in the **@Jobs** table with a prefix. Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE @Jobs 
SET [Name] = 'OLA - ' + [Name]
```

*NOTE: I haven't tested this solution but it should work.*

Where I work, we have a completely custom deployment script that deploys the jobs and uses the individual underlying object scripts so that we can deploy with our own default configs, job names and other settings.